# Failed to push files to /Android/data/ on Samsung Tab S8, but it works fine on Tab S7

Tags: android, shell, adb, samsung

The console output is like this (there is 1 file and 1 subfolder in current directory, and 10 files in this subfolder):

```
user$ adb push * /sdcard/Android/data/com.xxx.xxx.xxx
adb: error: failed to copy 'Subfolder/subfile1.txt' to '/sdcard/Android/data/com.xxx.xxx.xxx/Subfolder/subfile1.txt': remote secure_mkdirs failed: Operation not permitted
Subfolder/: 10 files pushed, 0 skipped. 4.3 MB/s (29693 bytes in 0.007s)
adb: error: failed to read copy xxx.xxx.xxx/file.txt
file.txt: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 2.4 MB/s (1134 bytes in 0.000s)
adb: error: failed to read copy response
11 files pushed, 0 skipped. 1.6 MB/s (30827 bytes in 0.018s)
```

However, when entering the folder, the 'Subfolder' has already been created, but no file has been pushed (even if it shows '11 files pushed'). And after I tried to push again, there is no error showing and the 11 files are all successfully pushed.

This issue is not reproducible on Tab S7, which has the exact same Android OS version (12) and One UI version (4.1). I think it may be related to privilege changing in this device because the first column 'rws' on Tab S8 is different from 'rwx' on Tab S7, and the owner of files that I pushed is 'shell' on Tab S8 other than 'u0_xxxx' on Tab S7.

```
user$ adb shell ls -al /sdcard/Android/data/com.xxx.xxx.xxx
total 22
drwxrws---  6 u0_a361  ext_data_rw 3452 2022-07-21 11:11 .
drwxrws--x 28 media_rw ext_data_rw 3452 2022-07-21 11:11 ..
drwxrws--- 15 shell    ext_data_rw 3452 2022-07-21 11:12 folder
```

Similarly, if I mkdir under /sdcard/Android or /sdcard on Tab S8, the user is 'u0_a192':

```
gts8wifi:/sdcard/Android $ ls -al
total 23
drwxrws---  3 u0_a192  media_rw    3452 2022-06-30 15:44 .Trash
drwxrws--x 29 media_rw ext_data_rw 3452 2022-07-28 18:02 data
drwxrws--x  3 media_rw media_rw    3452 2022-07-26 17:20 media
drwxrws--x  3 media_rw ext_obb_rw  3452 2022-04-21 18:39 obb
drwxrws---  2 u0_a192  media_rw    3452 2022-07-28 18:02 NewFolder
```

And if I mkdir under /sdcard/Android/data, the user becomes 'shell' (any command like 'chmod' is not permitted on this device):

```
gts8wifi:/sdcard/Android/data $ ls -al
total 90
drwxrws--x 30 media_rw ext_data_rw 3452 2022-07-28 18:03 .
drwxrws--x  7 media_rw media_rw    3452 2022-07-28 18:02 ..
-rw-rw----  1 u0_a192  ext_data_rw    0 2022-04-21 18:39 .nomedia
drwxrws---  3 u0_a156  ext_data_rw 3452 2022-06-29 16:22 com.samsung.android.app.notes
drwxrws---  3 system   ext_data_rw 3452 2022-04-21 18:39 com.samsung.android.forest
drwxrws---  2 shell    ext_data_rw 3452 2022-07-28 18:03 NewFolder
```

Is there any way to solve this problem? The only workaround I could find out is to create all of the folders and subfolders first, then the adb push works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs due to different permissions for different directories when created using mkdir & adb push

The first item in the list items after executing ls -al represents the access permissions on the files.

```
d directory
r read the file or directory
w write to the file or directory
x execute the file or search the directory
s set-uid : when run this program: the program doesn't run with the privilege of user who ran it, instead, with the privilege of file owner.
```

```
u the user who owns the file (usually you)
g members of the group to which the owner belongs
o all other users
```

The access permissions for all three types of user can be given as a string of nine characters

```
user - group - others
r w x - r w x - r w x
```

Have a look at the difference in access permissions of folders created through adb push, and the ones created using mkdir/ directly in filesystem.

**The difference lies in the read permission for others** ,which explains the error you are facing. 
You can change access permissions in a unix system (Android here) by using the command

```
chmod mode filename
```

Futher reading [Unix cheatsheet](https://web.pa.msu.edu/people/abdo/unixcc.html)

Comment: Thank you Mritunjay, but it does not work because any privilege command is not permitted on this device (I added some details in the description), so is there any other thing I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: There's no other way I know of apart from creating folders first and pushing files after (your workaround).